# Polylines from csv - different behaviour than from string literal

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, encoding, google-polyline

I read a lot of SO topics about encoding to get an idea what's wrong with my code, but I'm still stucked.

I want to decode Google polylines which I have in csv file. I am using polyline library which works fine. The problem is that some lines from csv can't be processed when I read them from csv, but when I just pass that polyline as string literal it works okay. I presume it's some encoding issue, because polylines that make problem have two consecutive backslashes and/or backticks.

```
import csv
import polyline

INPUT_FILE = 'sample_input.csv'

csv.register_dialect(
    'mydialect',
    delimiter = ',',
    quotechar = '"',
    doublequote = True,
    skipinitialspace = True,
    quoting = csv.QUOTE_ALL)

with open(INPUT_FILE, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as csv_file:

    read = csv.reader(csv_file, dialect='mydialect')

    header = next(read, [])

    for row in read:

        site_id = row[0]
        encoded_polyline = row[1]

        print(site_id)

        try:
            decoded = polyline.decode(encoded_polyline)
            print(decoded)
        except:
            print(encoded_polyline)

        print()
```

Sample polyline is:

```
"dk`mEg}jx[STEFGJKRONUVSTkAtAiAlAsA~Ag@p@[^[`@e@p@KTSVU\\GHGNEHEHCFAFAFAFAPAP?N?B@T@V@R@F"
```

Please pay attention that here it also appears with only one backslash and no backtick - probably similar encoding issue?

Any help would be appreciated, especially explanation why behaviour with string literal is not the same as with string variable.

Comment: are you getting an error when decoding the polyline? I just ran the string with no issue.

Comment: I have no issue too when I pass that string into polyline.decode function, but there's an error (    byte = ord(value[index]) - 63

IndexError: string index out of range) when it's read from csv. Lines without backslashes are processed okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should solve your problem

```
decoded = polyline.decode(encoded_polyline.replace('\\\\','\\'))
```

Comment: Thanks! I just bumped to that solution on another SO topic, tried it and it worked! I thought I already tried it hours ago, but I guess I used "\\" to "\" (really basic mistake) and then when it wasn't working I started to think it must be some encoding problem and spent a lot of time on a wild goose chase :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, then realized that the polyline included the elevation field, hence if you want to get the x,y,z you should use the parameter is3d=True.

`decoded = polyline.decode(encoded_polyline,is3d=True)`